# How to add parameter in jQuery document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

How can I add parameters to document.ready function? because in javascript it does not have any issue, but when I use jquery and try to set parameters, there is an error always and can't get the parameter

```
function toggleItem(el, el2, el3, el4, el5, el6) {
            var item1 = document.getElementById(el2);
            if (item1.style.display === "none") {
                item1.style.display ="flex";
            } else {
                item1.style.display ="none";
            }
```

and my statis jquery like

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                if($('btn-overlay').css("display") == "block") {
                    $('.btn-mainbrand').attr("style", "margin-bottom:30px;");
                } 
                    $('.btn-mainbrand').attr("style", "margin-top:100px;");
            });
```

my HTML code:

```
<div class="card-mainbrand" id="card-main{{$key}}">
                        <img src="{{url('storage/photos/brand/'.$item->image_bg)}}" alt="">
                        <div class="mainbrand-content">
                            <div class="logo-mainbrand">
                                <img src="{{url('storage/photos/brand/'. $item->image_logo2)}}" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-mainbrand" id="mainbrand-item2{{$key}}">
                                <p>{{$item->subtitle}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-mainbrand" id="mainbrand-item1{{$key}}">
                                <a href="{{url('brand/'.$item->id)}}">
                                    <p>DISCOVER MORE</p>
                                </a>
                                <a href="{{$item->url}}">
                                    <p>GO TO WEBSITE</p>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            @if(count($item->subBrand) != 0)
                            <div class="btn-overlay">
                                <div onclick="toggleItem('btn-overlays{{$key}}','mainbrand-item1{{$key}}','mainbrand-item2{{$key}}','card-main{{$key}}','ic-def{{$key}}','ic-op{{$key}}')" class="btn-open-overlay" id="btn-overlays{{$key}}">
                                    <p>EXPLORE SUB BRAND</p>
                                    <i class='bx bx-chevron-down' id="ic-def{{$key}}"></i>
                                    <i class='bx bx-x' id="ic-op{{$key}}"></i>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            @endif
                        </div>            
                    </div>
```

I'm using laravel live wire.

Comment: whats the error message shows in the code you provide?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please add the error message and reduce your example code to the minimum needed

Answer (score 0):

I think It is better to use Alpine.js library with liverwire instead of JQuery.

Comment: how example code ?

Comment: I think It is hard to explain a javascript library within several lines.Check Alpine.js documentation You will find  Your answer there.relation between Alpine.js and livewire is like relation between bootstrap and JQuery.